# PHP: SQL Data in HTML table not getting ordered

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to order my data in two ways. When I click the link the table does not update.

**HTML:**

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<table id='customers'>
<thead>
    <tr>            
        <th><a href='?orderBy=producto'> Producto</a></th>
        <th>Unidad</th>
        <th>Candidad Necesaria</th>
        <th>Precio Objetivo por Unidad</th>
        <th><a href='?orderBy=ctot_obj'>Valor Producto<a/></th>
        <th>Remover Entrada</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

PHP:

```
$orderBy = array('producto', 'ctot_obj');
$order = 'producto';
if (isset($_GET['orderBy']) && in_array($_GET['orderBy'], $orderBy)) {
    $order = $_GET['orderBy'];
}

$query_ord = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM busca ORDER BY '.$order'");
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
$query_ord = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM busca ORDER BY '" . $order . "'");
```

Comment: Not working. If I echo the query seems legit but apparently the table does not get reorganized.

Comment: Run the query output against MySQL directly -- do you get correct output? If so, then could you edit your question and add a code snippet where you iterate through `$query_ord` and echo the rows/cols? Issue might be there.

Comment: I fixed it. I had and early query that was creating an endless loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.` fron your sql query and try.

```
$query_ord = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM busca ORDER BY '{$order}'");
```

Answer (score 0):

echo `'`  html code  `'`;

in html code use `"` instead of `'`

use `#` in href or `./`

```
echo '<tr><table id="customers">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th><a href="./?orderBy=producto"> Producto</a></th>
    <th>Unidad</th>
    <th>Candidad Necesaria</th>
    <th>Precio Objetivo por Unidad</th>
                <th><a href="?orderBy=ctot_obj">Valor Producto<a/></th>
                <th>Remover Entrada</th>
            </thead>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this make some changes in the code. Suppose your page name is `details.php`, so make following changes:

```
<a href='details.php?orderBy=producto'>
```

Now use this `orderBy` in your query by fetching its values in a variable like:

```
$orderBy = $_GET['orderBy'];
```